# How interface::class.java works for umimplemented methods in that interface

Tags: java, kotlin, class, methods, interface

```
fun main(){
    val bal = Host::class.java
}

interface Host{
    fun void()
}
```

I have created simple code here,
One Interface that was instantiated here with a class like Host::class.java. I see bal take the type as Class. Its creating a class from interface thats ok but how it can create class from interface without the methods that need to be implemented as a contract between interface.
Also when i call bal. i couldn't find void() method from bal instance.

What is the reason it differs from normal implementation of interface in a class? I'm really for any kind of answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bal` is an instance of [`Class<Host>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), not an instance of `Host`. `Class` is a class that contains information about the definition of a class or interface, and does not represent an instance of that class or interface. It is typically used for [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html). No class implementation of your interface has been created in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tenfour04 one follow up question. You said "It is typically used for reflection". What does reflection mean here and what is its use? :)

Comment: I linked to a description of what reflection is in my answer. It lets you inspect code at runtime. For example, get a list of methods in a class by their names as Strings. It’s commonly used in serialization libraries that convert between classes and Strings so you can save data easily or work with data from the Web easily.